# Help setting up a dns nameserver for parking domains

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, nameserver

I need to be able to create name server entries for new domains being registered and need some help in setting up a name server on the internet. I am looking for some good resources - prefereably with a windows machine.

Any tips to help getting started greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Some providers will park your name for free (they almost always put advertising up on your sites). Some charge a small fee to put up an "under construction" or similar page.

Otherwise you just have to get regular hosting like any other site. A very basic plan will do if you have only one "under construction" or "coming soon" page to host.

**Edit:**
If your interested in running your own servers (which is not clear by the title), I recommend installing [Bind9 for Windows](https://www.isc.org/software/bind), available for free from the [ISC](https://www.isc.org/).

Bind is the most widely supported free DNS server, and there are [many tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=Bind9+Tutorial) that are pretty easy to understand (though most will have to be adapted, as they're written for *nix). The server will come with sample configuration files, the complete Admin Reference Manual, and supporting tools for diagnosing problems (it's a pretty well rounded download).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. Like I said, I am interested in setting up my own nameserver, not using a provider.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a windows machine as a server on the internet. I will probably get flamed for saying that. I don't care.

That being said, powerdns is really nice. Bind is widely used, but I've found it too limiting.

Though, it will probably be easier to do what Chris said and just rent a server that will allow you to use unlimited domain names. Maybe a VPS with a control panel as it seems a GUI is something you'd want.